# How to run a Java Applet on top of my own window handle

Tags: java, applet, win32gui

I try to start an applet on top of my own Win32 window. In other words, I need to develop a java applet container on windows. Where can I find the doc or sample code to start an applet in my own application. Browsing the source code of Chrome did not reveal the answer.

So : 
how to deliver my Window handle to the JVM so it places the applet on my HWND?
And what is needed to position/size the applet.

The applet container should run in a UNIFACE environment. In the current setup customers use an OCX container with an OCX in it which contains the applet. Also they use the HTML widget which is based on the Chrome browser. The OCX widget is discontinued and the Chrome browser is way too fat. So the UNIFACE lab is questioned for a Java Container like the OCX container widget.

Thanks in advance for your time
Jasper de Keijzer

Comment: Are you sure you want an *applet*, and not, say, a Swing GUI?

Comment: I agree with kviiri just create a swing GUI very simple and you should be able to port some of your applet code into it.

Comment: In particular look at the JFrame class.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebBrowser control of visual c++ as wrapper for your applet.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041(v=vs.85).aspx

The idea is this way:

1. Win32 window holds WebBrowser control
2. WebBrowser control holds the applet

Remember to install java for your Internet Explorer

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not accepted by the customers of UNIFACE, they want a container which is small and fast to load.